# How to convert byte[] in IFormFile in asp.net MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using IFormFile to add images and then convert the file into byte array and save it to my database, than I'm able to read the image and display it.

however from the view, where I add the images when I open the saved record in edit mode I'm not able to see the previously saved image.

so on the view I have this code:

```
<input type="file" asp-for="BAN_IMAGE_FILE">
```

on my model
I have the following property

```
    public byte[] BAN_IMAGE {get;set;}

    private IFormFile _BAN_IMAGE_FILE;

    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile BAN_IMAGE_FILE
    {
        get => _BAN_IMAGE_FILE;
        set
        {
            _BAN_IMAGE_FILE = value;

            if (_BAN_IMAGE_FILE != null)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    _BAN_IMAGE_FILE.CopyTo(ms);
                    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                    BAN_IMAGE = fileBytes;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

so as you can see what I do is when the file is choosen it converts it into a byte array so when I click save button the data is saved.

what I want to do is when I click on edit I want to get the byte array and convert it into a FormFile so it is displayed on the screen, any suggestions how to do it?

Edit Method in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated != true)
            return NotFound();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var tEvents = await _context.TEVENTS.Include(x => x.BANNERS).Include(x=>x.PHOTO_GALLERY).Include(x=>x.EVENT_TYPES)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TE_ROWID.Equals(id));

        ViewBag.EvenTypes = GetEventTypes();

        if (tEvents == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(tEvents);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post in your question `GET` and `POST` methods for your `Edit` action in your controller?

Comment: sure, will update the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to use viewmodel for `IFormFile` type, like it is written in [>>DOCUMENTATION<<](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

Another thing, I have no idea how your view file looks, with saved image, but to get your image you supposed to get it with something like:

```
@model YourViewModel
(...)
@if (item.AktualnosciImage != null)
            {
//if the file exists in database
                <div style="background-image: url(data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.YourViewModelsImageProperty))"></div>
            }
            @if (item.AktualnosciImage == null)
            {

//if the file does not exists in database
                <div style="background-image: url(/img/Aktualnosci/default.jpg)"></div>
            }
```

Comment: I don't have any problem while displaying the image, the issue is : I'm not able to covnert from byte array to FormFile

Comment: @Licentia I had the same problem today. I was explained, that IFormFile you are not able to set up programatically, only user can do it via browser. More you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297803/how-to-parse-byte-array-from-model-with-iformfile-from-viewmodel-for-file-uplo?noredirect=1#comment93478301_53297803