# How to parse byte[] array from model with IFormFile from viewmodel for file uploading controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, iformfile

I have Core MVC application, when for specific entity I have following model:

```
public class Aktualnosci
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Tytul { get; set; }
        public string Tresc { get; set; }
        public DateTime Dzien { get; set; }
        public byte[] AktualnosciImage { get; set; }
    }
```

For uploading the image I am using `IFormFile` property in my viewmodel, that is called by controller, according to the documentation from [>>HERE<<](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
public class AktualnosciCreateVM
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wypełnić pole.")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Max 40 znaków.")]
        public string Tytul { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wypełnić pole.")]
        public string Tresc { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wypełnić pole.")]
        public DateTime Dzien { get; set; }
        public IFormFile AktualnosciImage { set; get; }
    }
```

And it is used for creating and editing of the entity. Right now I have troubles with parsing `public IFormFile AktualnosciImage { set; get; }` and `public byte[] AktualnosciImage { get; set; }` in my controller's `GET` method, to have returned viewmodel:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Moderatorzy")]
        // GET: Aktualnosci/Edit/5
        public IActionResult Edit(long? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            Aktualnosci aktualnosci = aktualnosciRepository.AktualnosciList
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == id);
            if (aktualnosci == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                aktualnosciCreateVM.ID = aktualnosci.ID;
                aktualnosciCreateVM.Tytul = aktualnosci.Tytul;
                aktualnosciCreateVM.Tresc = aktualnosci.Tresc;
                aktualnosciCreateVM.Dzien = aktualnosci.Dzien;
//this one gives me an error v
                aktualnosciCreateVM.AktualnosciImage = aktualnosci.AktualnosciImage.ToArray();
                return View(aktualnosciCreateVM);

            }
        }
```

The compilation error is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'

Is there any way to parse this 2 properties?

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input programatically (it can only be set by the user selecting a file in the browser), so it would be pointless to try and set the value of the `IFormFile` property

Comment: @StephenMuecke In that case how can I pass img from database to my VM, if in VM I have `IFormFile` type property, that is required to upload the file?

Comment: `IFormFile` is for uploading a file only. Its not clear what you want. If you want to display an image in the view (to indicate what the user previously uploaded), then you can convert the `byte[]` to a `Base64String` and display it in an `<img>` element. Although typically you would save the uploaded file to the server and just save the path/display name in the db, and the include that in the view

Comment: @StephenMuecke good point. I removed already `aktualnosciCreateVM.AktualnosciImage = aktualnosci.AktualnosciImage.ToArray();` from my controller. Just right now I am getting `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` for `await aktualnosci.AktualnosciImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);`. I need to figure out what I did wrong...

Comment: I cannot see anything in your question about `await aktualnosci.AktualnosciImage.CopyToAsync(memoryStream)` - you will need to ask a new question about that

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah, I will try to figure it out first by myself. Anyway thank you for help with `IFormFile`.